# Execute command on EC2 instance from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a Rails 5 application running on Elastic beanstalk. From my app I want to restart a docker container that is running on another EC2 instance.

This is the part of the code I wrote:

`system("ssh -i ~/.ssh/<ssh_key> <EC2 instance IP> 'docker restart <container_name>')`

I added the SSH key manually to my instance in the ~/.ssh folder and run `chmod 400` to it. When running manually this command after ssh into elastic beanstalk it is successfull but when the application is running it does not restart the servers successfully.

My guess is that the problem is that I added the ssh key via `ec2-user`, and the running application is using another user. If that is the case how can I achieve this? I tried changing the user and adding the ssh key for the `webapp` user, but after `sudo su webapp` it says `This account is currently not available.`

Is there a better way overall to achieve the same thing?

Comment: The error log is the following

`Warning: Identity file /home/webapp/.ssh/<key> not accessible: No such file or directory.
Could not create directory '/home/webapp/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a service for exactly this, [AWS systems manager run command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

Look at using the [SendCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/SSM/Client.html#send_command-instance_method) in the AWS sdk. By passing in your instance ID and the command to run, it’ll execute for you.

Using the existing AWS-RunShellScript document you can run the command without worrying about connecting via SSH.

Some examples from cli [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html)